# How to configure Multi Wan in nethserver firewall

Tags: proxy, wan

We are using Nethserver as router as firewall. We configure web proxy in our firewall. When client users access google web page the internet getting very slow and disconnected simultaneously. How to overcome this problem. We have 2 wan connections. They configured as balance mode.

Comment: Could you tell us a little bit more about your configuration? How many network-interfaces, how did you configure them, green network, red network for example. And the config file of squid could help also.

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe ask your question on https://community.nethserver.org - you'll get in contact with a large and enthusiastic community.